# database options in django settings file are not working

Tags: mysql, django

I was setting AWS EC2 instance on our company's new AWS account. and I've been faced some issue with database connection. below is occurred warning message on terminal.

```sh
(django_mysql.W003) The character set is not utf8mb4 for database connection 'default'
    HINT: The default 'utf8' character set does not include support for all Unicode characters. 
It's strongly recommended you move to use 'utf8mb4'. 
See: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/checks.html#django-mysql-w003-utf8mb4
```

I've already specified charset option in settings file.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            'use_unicode': True,
        },
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 30,
    }
}
```

I thought It would be fine but terminal shows me same warning message.
and then database is also set to `utf8mb4`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUIDl.png)

how can I resolve this issue? thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem:

- My database had `utf8mb4` encoding
- My Django settings file was configured to use: `'charset': 'utf8mb4'`
- And yet, I was receiving `The character set is not utf8mb4 for database connection 'default'` Warnings

I found that the problem is that I was using some older versions of some python libraries running on a newer version of MySQL.

In my original configuration, which was working, I was using MySQL 5.7 and had in my Python Virtual Env:

```
mysqlclient==1.4.4
django-mysql==3.7.1
```

Once I upgraded to MySQL 8.0 the warnings started. It turns out those versions of `mysqlclient` and `django-mysql` cause this problem.

By upgrading them to:

```
mysqlclient==2.2.0
django-mysql==4.11.0
```

the warnings went away.